# Mouse over event on the column of a GWT celltable

Tags: gwt

I want to create a mouse over event on the column of a GWT celltable. Can you help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean CellTable, you can try something like that...

```
table.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<IdObject>()
    {

        @Override
        public void onCellPreview(
            CellPreviewEvent<IdObject> event)
        {
            if ("mouseover".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
                Element cellElement = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast();
                // play with element
            }
        }
    });
```

UDP: Method for getting cell value.

```
private String getElementValue(
    Element element)
{
    Element child = element.getFirstChildElement().cast();
    while (child != null)
    {
        element = child;
        child = element.getFirstChildElement().cast();
    }
    return element.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
}
```

Comment: Hi globerz,

Thank you very much. Its working but i dont knw how to set it for a particular column. For eg. I need mouse over event of the 6th column of the celltable. Can you please help me?



Thanks in Advance,
Gnik

Comment: CellPreviewEvent has int method getColumn :)

Comment: Hi globerz, Thank you very much. Its working. But i've a issue. I need to get the data of the column, in which i'm over the mouse. I'm trying it. If you know. Please help me.  Thanks in Advance, Gnik

Comment: Not only that mouse over column also the other columns of the particular row. Thanks.

Comment: so.. you can get an object of a row (object = table.getVisibleItem(event.getindex()) and calculate its value in table (table.getColumt(event.getColumn()).getValue(object)). Does it fit? +)

Answer (score 4):

I assume one would want to get the data model (or object) associated with the column, you can simply call

```
event.getValue()
```

This returns the column data model, which is actually the model the table uses for the entire row.